# Use window form C# sort negative values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to write C# program for window form. When i use 
{ Detail_ListBox.Sorted = true; } to sort my ListBox in ascending order but i get which is not what i wanted
-1
-2
-3
 0
 1
 2
 3

Its able to sort the positive values but i suppose to sort the negative & positive value to become
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
This is just an example the actual values can include from -300 to +300.
Anyone kind to help me what statements should i use in order to sort both -ve & +ve values?

Comment: That's a proper alphabetical sort.  Other than using data binding, consider a ListView with View = List instead.  You can use its ListViewItemSorter property to assign a custom sorter that interprets the items as numbers instead of strings.

Comment: var list = String.Format("{0,2} {1,40} {2,40} {3,40} {4,45} {5,15}", ND_TextBox.Text, PN_ComBox.Text, NN_TextBox.Text, Cus_textBox.Text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"),checkout.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")); Those are the codes i use for a row , i wanted to sort by column {0,2}

Answer (score 1):

When you use { Detail_ListBox.Sorted = true; } it sorts values like string. You should at first sort int values and then put them to ListBox without Detail_ListBox.Sorted = true;

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of integers, like so:

```
List<int> integers = somelist;
```

You can sort it with:

```
integers.Sort();
```

And then assign to the listbox:

```
Detail_ListBox.DataSource = integers;
```

Or:

```
Detail_ListBox.Items = integers.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListBox` has some `DataSource` you can try sorting the `DataSource` instead. If not you can try this extension method:

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static void SortBy<TElement>(this ListBox list,
                              Func<TElement, object> fieldSelector)
    {
        var items = list.Items.OfType<TElement>()
                        .OrderBy(fieldSelector)
                        .Cast<object>().ToArray();
        list.BeginUpdate();
        list.Items.Clear();
        list.Items.AddRange(items);
        list.EndUpdate();
    }
    public static void SortByDescending(this ListBox list,
                                        Func<TElement, object> fieldSelector)
    {
        var items = list.Items.OfType<TElement>()
                        .OrderByDescending(fieldSelector)
                        .Cast<object>().ToArray();
        list.BeginUpdate();
        list.Items.Clear();
        list.Items.AddRange(items);
        list.EndUpdate();
    }           
}

//Usage
listBox1.SortBy<object>(x=>x);
//if your listBox1 has elements of the same type Item, use it like this:
listBox1.SortBy<Item>(x=>x.SomeProperty);
```